# want to play the ringtone in vibration mode?

Tags: android

I want to play the default ringtone in silent mode of android phone?
I am using this code

```
  if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {           
           Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
           phoneNumber = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);                                            

           int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
           audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, maxVolume, 0);

           Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE); 
           Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(mContext, notification);
           r.play();
  }
```

The problem in this code is that when the call comes the ringtone is played but after the phone is cut or is missed the ringtone is still playing mode

Comment: dont you need to make the stop()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code inside the `onRecieve()` of you `BroadcastReciever`:

```
Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE); 
Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(mContext, notification);
if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {           
   Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
   phoneNumber = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);                                            

   int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
   audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, maxVolume, 0);

   r.play();
}else{
    if(r.isPlaying()) r.stop();
}
```

Comment: @user3756346 still crashing?

Comment: hmmm after the phone cut app crashes

Comment: this is because you have hot initialized the `Ringtone r` correctly. wait while i update the answer.